Installing `go get github.com/gorilla/mux` throws `access is denied` error on Windows
I want to install github.com/gorilla/mux but it throws an access is denied error on Windows.
Command:
go get github.com/gorilla/mux

Output:
go: downloading github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.1 go: github.com/gorilla/mux: open C:\Users\Golang\pkg\mod\cache\download\github.com\gorilla\mux@v\v1.8.1.lock: Access is denied.


This question is similar to: Access denied when using go get. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
